# Are my sentences grammatically correct if I use these structures of "Would"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Are my sentences grammatically correct *(even if there is no other pre-condition)* :

**Structure:** **Would be + Verb in the past participle (Passive Sentence)**

*Example:*

1. Obama would be sent.
2. We would be given the guitar.

**Structure:** **Would have + No Verb**

3. I would have a pen.
4. Rahul would have a book.
5. We would not have any money.

**Structure:** **Would have + Verb in past participle**

6. I would have come home.
7. He would have left for Delhi.

Comment: All are correct as they stand, but the meanings are not clear without an _if_ clause.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are these sentences grammatically correct, and can they stand alone as a sentence?

1. I didn’t watch you play, otherwise, I would have been your fan.

2. I would have been playing since morning.

3. She would have been reading for two hours.

4. I would have been sent.

5. We would have been given water.

Comment: Exactly the same applies to these sentences 2 - 5 as to those in your original question - they are correct, but they seem to need an _if_ clause before or after. Sentence 1 is grammatical but not very idiomatic. (Not being able to watch someone play a sport on a particular occasion doesn't stop you from being their fan!)